# Can't connect to SQL Server using IIS APPPOOL User

Tags: sql-server, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI that is calling a SQL Server (currently 2008, but will migrate on something newer soon). Authentication is Windows authentication. I have given the IIS Apppool that executes the WebAPI the rights to access the database.

When I use the following connection string, everything works:

```
Server=localhost; Database=LPG; Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

For the production system, the WebAPI and the database server are probably on different machines, so I want to use the name of the server instead of localhost.

```
Server=my.server.com; Database=LPG; Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

With this connection string, I get the following error.

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

This is probably because the IIS APPPOOL - User is a local account and when calling `my.server.com` it can't use local accounts.

Does anyone knows how to resolve that problem?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: On production machine give access to SQL server to identity used to configure app pool. but since you said its local account it may not get recognized on SQL server. So you need to replace it with domain user (network) with minimum required privileges.

Comment: Hey Pankaj, thanks for the tip! I just created a domain user and used it to run the application pool (Identity > User defined). I added this user to the folders that contains the WebAPI, but server requests fail. Do I need to change something else, when I want to run the app pool with that domain user?

Comment: Do you mean request to web server where web apis are hosted or SQL server failed? Did you give access to this identity on SQL server?

Comment: The request to the web api fails

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your production server may not be setup for delegation. The web server and the db server must have a relationship so the user on the browser flows through to the database.

Comment: They'll be in the same windows domain. Hm. maybe like Pankaj suggest, using a domain user? But how can I incorporate the domain user in the SQL-Call in the WebAPI-Server?

Comment: It's more than being in the same domain. you are trying to pass the web browser's user to the web server, who in turn wants to pass that id on to the database. This is called delegation.

It's really a task for a network admin, but maybe this will get you started

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739740(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: From what I experience, the user that is used to run the web api is the one that is used to call the SQL server. Thanks for the tip, I'll have a read then :)